# React Native: Height vs flex

Tags: reactjs, react-native, height, flexbox

While setting height of multiple components in a view, is there any difference between setting the height in terms of flex or height?

For eg,

```
1) <View>
       <View style={{flex:1}}>
       </View>
       <View style={{flex:3}}>
       </View>
   </View

2) var windowSize = Dimensions.get('window');
   <View>
       <View style={{height:windowSize.height/4}}>
       </View>
       <View style={{height:windowSize.height*3/4}}>
       </View>
   </View>
```

Comment: you can define the height using pixel or percentage. otherwise flex height will increase based on content size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you rotate a device flex is responsive where as window isn't.

For example if the device dimension is 1280 x 720, it would result in the following:

Flex: 
portrait mode height = 1280. 
Landscape mode height = 720

Window: 
portrait mode height = 1280. 
Landscape mode height = 1280

Window retrieves your dimensions once when the component mounts. Yes you can manually add detectors for window when a screen rotates, but i don't see why you want to go through that much effort when flex is short and simple.

Comment: Thanks @A-Man. Got what you are trying to say. I knew about manually adding detectors for window when screen rotates but wanted to clarify my doubt about flex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For flex the size reference is its parent views layout size, whereas if you use window dimensions , it takes the whole window size as the reference. Try setting some height and width in 1) and see.

Comment: Thanks @agent_hunt. I was a bit confused with the use of flex. Now it's clarified a bit.