# React Native: Flex vs Height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to React native.

Iv seen a similar question asking this but it does not answer what im looking for.

My question is, whats the difference (performance, behaviour) between:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, background: 'blue' }}>
   <Text style={{ flex: 0.8, background: 'red' }}>Hello</Text>
   <Text style={{ flex: 0.2, background: 'brown' }}>World</Text>
</View>
```

and

```
<View style={{ height: '100%', background: 'blue' }}>
   <Text style={{ height: '80%', background: 'red' }}>Hello</Text>
   <Text style={{ height: '20%', background: 'brown' }}>World</Text>
</View>
```

because i dont see any difference in using the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: Height vs flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400775/react-native-height-vs-flex)

Comment: When it comes to device rotation , flex will be responsive over using heights !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post - it has to do with the responsiveness, not the pixel percentage. [React Native: Height vs flex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41400775/8233728)